# Objective C - Animation Blocks, multiparameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question... how is programmatically reached the Animation blocks?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"repositionAnimation" context:nil];

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[view setFrame:viewRect];

[view setAlpha:0];

...

...

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How the messages are stored and processed on commitAnimations ???

I just guess that the begin function invokes some kind of holder for messages, storing the messages somehow and process them in loop ?

is there a way to work with a messages some kind like in argument lists???

Answer (score 2):

You are using the animation proxy when you call [UIView beginAnimations:context:]. If you want to manage animations explicitly, use [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can monitor progress of a view's layer by periodically (using a timer) checking the layer's *presentationLayer*.